# How to handle intercommunication between windows

Tags: extjs4

I am able to open a new window by clicking on a button in another window, but my requirement is that I should be able to listen to the events generated from the other window.

Can anybody help me? How can I register the events from one window and listen to them in the other, so that intercommunication can happen?

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be that you shouldn't. Register your listeners in a common controller--that way, whatever events are fired by either window can be captured by the controller, and the controller can decide what needs to happen to what window in what circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I use TIBCO PageBus (http://developer.tibco.com/pagebus/default.jsp) for inter application events within my ExtJs applications. It is a JavaScript event bus. For instance, similar to what you describe, I have an editor window, which has a button to display a preview window. The editor window on a save, raises a update content event on the page bus, which the preview window subscribes to, upon receiving the event it refreshes the preview.

One of the advantages of this approach is that many clients can subscribe to events, if you have a complex application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you please help me by providing a small example which i can refer

Comment: All of this can be accomplished via controllers in ExtJS without the need for integrating a 3rd party extension. And using the new event domains in ExtJS 4.2, you're not even limited to only component events.